# Permutations with repetition for some elements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we have $N$ slots, each of which can be filled with $X$ options, but $2$ of these slots can only be filled in $1$ way (out of $X$ ways), then what is the number of permutations possible ?

For example $N=4$,$\ X=\{a,b,c\}$ and one element must be $a$ and one must be $c$ then the number of permutation in this case I've calculated as follows:
$\{Possible\ configuration\} \implies Permutations\ for\ this\ configuration $

$\{a,a,a,c\} \implies 4 $

$\{a,a,b,c\} \implies 12$

$\{a,a,c,c\} \implies 6$

$\{a,b,b,c\} \implies 12$

$\{a,b,c,c\} \implies 12$

$\{a,c,c,c\} \implies 4$

Thus Total = $50$

I am looking for a generalized formula for this (possibly with even 2 replaced with a parameter)

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do the count for your case in another way. There are $3^4$ strings with no restriction.

We count the *bad* strings, that are missing at least one of $a$ and $c$.

There are $2^4$ strings with no $a$, and $2^4$ with no $c$. But we have double-counted the one string with no $a$ **and** no $c$. Thus there are $31$ bad strings, and therefore $50$ good.

**Exactly** the same idea works if we have $n$ slots, and $k$ letters that include $a$ and $c$, and we want to have at least one $a$ and at least one $c$.

There are $k^n$ strings. The number of bad strings is $(k-1)^n+(k-1)^n -(k-2)^n$. Subtract.

The Inclusion/Exclusion technique should be useful for variants of your problem.

Comment: You mean $2^4$ strings. I get the idea - thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I am weak on exponents. But I did mean the $32-1$.